# How to search post with multiple tags but not containing a specific one?

Tags: support, tags, search

I was wondering if it is posible to search post with multiple tags but skipping a specific one.

For example, I can search multiple tags in the way:

```
[java] or [junit] or [regex]
```

But if I want to exclude [android] tag, is it posible to do this like:

```
[java] or [junit] or [regex] not [android]
```

Comment: A wonderful question. It will be useful for most question hunters

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This option exists already:

[image]

In order to do this, your search would be:

```
[java] or [junit] or [regex] -[android]
```

The `-` in front of `[android]` is used to signify `not`, and the `or` is, obviously, used to signify `or`.  *The `-` must be **right in front of** the tag to exclude (no spaces allowed).  Otherwise, the search fails.*

That search brings you to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+junit+or+regex+-android) with the proper results.

<del>But, you still need to [make sure that you do not put the `not` tag first.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49962/261238)</del>
It is actually also [now possible to search with a `not` at the beginning](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/#comment-7151), but it is slow.

*This feature is discussed on [the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/).*

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Btw, is it posible to save search criterias?

Comment: No, I don't believe that it is if you mean saving it as some sort of default search.  However, you could always bookmark the page or just save the link somewhere.

Comment: I tried what you want but still having trouble. I created [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261471/have-troubles-with-skipping-tags-with-android) mentioning it maybe you can give me your opinion.

Comment: You should add that the feature works only if there are no spaces between the `-` sign and the `[not-wanted-tag]`.

Comment: @ypercube Done.

Comment: @Fede For saving search criteria, what about just saving the URL somewhere? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+junit+or+regex+-android. Bookmark it or create a desktop shortcut or even just save it in a text file.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, I'm doing that but I think it's better to have that feature saved on our StackOverflow profile since bookmarks can be lost. Btw, I created this [post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261460/feature-request-for-saved-searches) but seems that people don't like that

Comment: Can I use "`and`" to get questions tagged with both of the tags? For ex: `[Java] and [Collections]`. I tried it , it's not working.

Comment: I got it. What all I need is `[Java] [Collections]` to get all question tagged in [Java] and [Collection].