# Have troubles with skipping tags with -[android]

Tags: support, tags, search

I want to search multiple tags and avoiding a specific one.

I've created this post to ask about it:

[How to search post with multiple tags but not containing a specific one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261383/how-to-search-post-with-multiple-tags-but-not-containing-a-specific-one)

But it seems that I'm still getting questions with the tag that I want to avoid:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Kevin I have favorited tags on java, junit and regex but not for android.

Comment: I see, that's a search, not favorite/ignore list.

Comment: I am having a lot of trouble finding an [tag:android] question using the same search query. Maybe caching?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug (maybe?) in the way the search looks at the negated tag. I thought there was a report for it on Meta Stack Exchange, but I'm having trouble finding it. There was also a feature request somewhere to allow some form of parentheses in search queries to specify what the OR/AND operators are being applied to, but I didn't look for that one (just remember seeing it).

Basically, it's looking for results that match one of the following:

- Has the tag [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) *or*
- Has the tag [junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/junit) *or*
- Has the tag [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), but not the tag [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)

The negation is only being applied to the last tag you entered. Unfortunately, there's no real way to work around this. Trying to modify the query to add the negation at each `or` like so...

```
[java] -[android] or [junit] -[android] or [regex] -[android]
```

...results in the search engine thinking you want questions tagged with all three [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/junit), and [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), but not [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) (negated three times).

For now, your best bet is to apply the negation to the most popular tag: [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). So something like...

```
[junit] or [regex] or [java] -[android]
```

...would exclude any Java questions which are also Android questions, at least getting rid of the *largest majority* of the Android questions which you don't want to see.

Answer (score 1):

You need to approach this like a coder.

```
[java] or [junit] or [regex] -[android]
```

That could be written in an `if` statement like below (of course, ignoring that this is invalid).

```
if ([java] || [junit] || [regex] && ![android])
```

Thus, it looks for questions that meet one of the following tag arrangements:

- [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)
- [junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/junit)
- [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) NOT [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)

I tried to search for both:

- `[java] or [junit] -[android] [regex] -[android]`
- `[java] or [junit] -[android] [regex]`

They were both unsuccessful, so I don't believe that it is possible to do it exactly as you wish.  You could search each or-separated option separately though.