# Search a few tags but not others

Tags: bug, tags

**Update:**

Given that this question got 10+ upvotes, a few different answers, and took over 2 days to be identified as a duplicate, makes me think that this information should be added to the [How to Search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) page.  When I come on this site looking to post answers, I know I'm only qualified to do so on a few topics, so it's imperative that I limit the questions I look at to only a few tags.  I imagine most others do the same and would benefit from finding this information in an obvious place (like the help/search page) rather than buried as a question like any other on the site.

---

**Original Post:**

I want to search tags [x] or [y] or [z] but not [a] and not [b].

Yes, I have seen [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261458/4573108).

But I'm still getting results with [a].  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Just tried your search and ggplot2 also shows up in the results, neither is excluded. Smells like a good bug.

Comment: Really glad to hear that.  I thought I was losing my mind!

Comment: I tried the query in the linked question, and the fifth result in my list was a question tagged with the "excluded" tag ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You can perform the search query you want if you group the tags together like this:

```
( [datatable] or [r] or [rstudio]) -[ggplot2] -[shiny] is:q
```

*Mind the space after the opening bracket and the is:q at the end*

---

It appears the query groups the `-` operator with the tag before it, e.g. it groups per `or`.

If you take a look at the query:

```
[datatable] or [r] or [rstudio] -[random]
```

the first result is a question tagged [random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/random):

[image]

However, if you switch the tags around, and group `[r] -[random]` in one `or`:

```
[datatable] or [rstudio] or [r] -[random]
```

you get the following:

[image]

So my guess is that this query is split into the following:

```
([datatable]) or ([r]) or ([rstudio] -[random])
```

Which means it looks for:

- a question with [datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable) OR
- a question with [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) OR
- a question with [rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rstudio) but not [random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/random)

Comment: Looks like grouping does the trick. Like this: `( [datatable] or [r] or [rstudio]) -[random] is:q`

Answer (score 4):

Some stats to help with debugging:

270,396 results are given with the query:

```
[datatable] or [r] or [rstudio] or [ggplot2] or [shiny]
```

Assuming that query is working all right, there's a total 270,396 with any of the 5 tags.

Some other queries and their results:

```
[ggplot2] or [shiny] | 35,886 results
[ggplot2] | 23,959 results
[shiny] | 13,798 results
[datatable] or [r] or [rstudio] -[ggplot2] | 269,306 results
[datatable] or [r] or [rstudio] -[shiny] | 269,242 results
[datatable] or [r] or [rstudio] -[ggplot2] -[shiny] | 269,239 results
[datatable] or [r] or [rstudio] or [ggplot2] or [shiny] is:question | 270,372 results
[ggplot2] or [shiny] is:question | 35,724 results
[datatable] or [r] or [rstudio] -[ggplot2] -[shiny] is:question | 234,648 results
```

What we're looking at is that the not operator isn't working, even when we only do one at a time. In fact, the very first question when [sorting by newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatable+or+r+or+rstudio+-shiny) of `[datatable] or [r] or [rstudio] -[shiny]` includes [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny), so it's not working even on one tag.

[image: Shiny!]

Oddly enough, the numbers do seem to be right when we add the `is:question` filter. And from the first few pages, I don't see any [ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ggplot2) or [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny) questions using that search. So that can be a work around until this bug gets addressed.